# Concatenate buffer with another buffer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, buffer

I'm very very confused in dealing with buffers ( copying, concatenating, etc) especially the usage of 'new' or malloc. i can code correctly without compilation errors, but problem occurs during runtime. i get runtime errors such as Access Violation, Assertion failed, etc..

For example, I've given source code of winhttp api demonstration from MSDN. In that code, they Query data from server using a while loop until all data received. after each query data is printed on console.

But I want it to store ( append ) data received each time into a new variable and finally print entire data on console. It would also be helpful in case of dlls

More details are provided in the code itself.

```
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <winhttp.h>

    #pragma comment(lib,"winhttp")
    using namespace std;

    int strcat_b(LPTSTR &dest, LPTSTR &src, int size);

    int main()
    {
        DWORD dwSize = 0;
        DWORD dwDownloaded = 0;

        LPSTR pszOutBuffer;
        LPTSTR pszFullCode;


        HINTERNET  hSession = NULL, 
                    hConnect = NULL,
                    hRequest = NULL;

        hSession = WinHttpOpen( L"Test WinHttp", WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);
        hConnect = WinHttpConnect( hSession, L"google.com", INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, 0);
        hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest( hConnect,  L"GET", 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0);
        WinHttpSendRequest( hRequest, WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0, WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0, 0, 0);
        WinHttpReceiveResponse( hRequest, NULL);

        do 
        {
            dwSize = 0;
            WinHttpQueryDataAvailable( hRequest, &dwSize);
            pszOutBuffer = new char[dwSize+1];
            ZeroMemory(pszOutBuffer, dwSize+1);
            WinHttpReadData( hRequest, (LPVOID)pszOutBuffer, dwSize, &dwDownloaded);

            // Actual code here was :
            printf("%s", pszOutBuffer);

            // I want to append pszOutBuffer into pszFullCode..
            // So I tried something like strcat(pszFullCode, pszOutBuffer)
            // And finally, when while loop ends, pszFullCode will be printed or Copied into another variable.

            // But I get "Access Violation error" at runtime.

            delete [] pszOutBuffer;

        } while (dwSize > 0);

        // Here it should be able print final result: printf("%s", pszFullCode);
        // In case of Dll, It should be able to copy data from pszFullCode to required Pointer.

        if (hRequest) WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
        if (hConnect) WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
        if (hSession) WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);

        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
```

Can anyone give some links to learn about concepts like this?? ( dealing with buffers, 'new' operator. malloc, minimizing access violation errors, etc  )

Thanks a lot..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that pretty much answers the question asked:

If you want to deal with "buffers, new operator, malloc, minimizing access violation errors", you should learn to use *Standard C++ Library*. It's full of useful stuff that will take the burden of managing memory of you.

For example, consider contiguos memory block. It can be expressed as:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> Block;
```

It's size (which can be read by `Block.size()`) is now 0. To allocate memory for it, we can write:

```
Block.reserve(size);
```

You can also do it in constructor directly:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> Block (size, 0); // fill it with zeros
```

Now, if you want to concatenate it with another block, it's as simple as:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> Block2;

Block.insert( Block.end(), Block2.begin(), Block2.end() );
```

or

```
std::copy(Block2.begin(), Block2.end(), std::back_inserter(Block));
```

Everything will reallocate properly and you won't get any runtime errors. If you however will ever be in need of supplying data to badly designed APIs or APIs written in C, you can still get raw acess to `vector`s memory by `.data()` method (C++11 only; use familiar `&Block[0]` in older compilers).

Comment: You should probably provide a fuller example of reserving memory within a vector before accessing it.

Comment: thanks.. i'll learn about that..

Comment: Keep in mind that the constructor that takes a size _resizes_ the vector (sets its size, allocating memory if needed), which is different from `reserve` (sets its capacity but not its size).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you did not initialize pszFullCode. If you wish to use some pointer as the first argument of strcat, you should previously make it point to a suitable buffer .

Comment: i tried initializing as pszFullCode = new char; but again got error.

Comment: This would be better: pszFullCode=new char[dwSize+1];

Comment: can you show it in given code. ( in fact, i tried all of your suggestions already, but didn't find solution. )  because, i want to append data in each loop. if i initialize using  pszFullCode=new char[dwSize+1];  in each loop, then it will not be appending.

Comment: If you know the maximum number of iterations (let's call that number maxIterations), then allocate the buffer of dwSize * maxIterations bytes. Otherwise, in each iteration you need to allocate a larger buffer, copy the old contents, and then call strcat. Note that std::string is able to do that reallocation automatically.